# Set ZF2 BjyAuthorize controller guards from Doctrine Entity

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, bjyauthorize

I have found a lot of questions on net that answers about setting controller guards directly in the config file but a lot less for getting the values from Doctrine Entity.

Can anyone please let me know about a single article that explains the process enough to start with.

I have already referred - [ZF2 - BjyAuthorize - How to Get Rules and Guards from a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264671/zf2-bjyauthorize-get-rules-and-guards-from-database-as-roles-are-already-get)

But no help in understanding where exactly should I register `DoctrineControllerGuardAdapterFactory` in the module config file.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Need the following settings -

```
'guards' => array(
    'YOUR_MODULE_NAME_controller_guard_adapter' => array(
        'object_manager' => 'doctrine.entity_manager.orm_default',
        'rule_entity_class' => 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Entity\RULE_ENTITY_NAME'
    ),
),
'service_manager' => array(
    'factories' => array(
        'YOUR_MODULE_NAME_controller_guard_adapter' => 'YOUR_MODULE_NAME\Factory\DoctrineControllerGuardAdapterFactory',
    ),
),
```

Now the factory will inject the `rules` in the `BjyAuthorize\Guard\Controller` constructor as mentioned in the [ZF2 - BjyAuthorize - How to Get Rules and Guards from a Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18264671/zf2-bjyauthorize-get-rules-and-guards-from-database-as-roles-are-already-get) link.